# Comparing mouse + Keyboard vs Touch Screen Input Devices?

Tags: input, touch-screen, keyboard, mouse

Is there any research that compares the User Experience of using the mentioned Input Devices ? 
Thanks

Edit: Basically for my dissertation i'm planning on creating a usable interface for a voting machine. I'd like to use a touchscreen and I need some kind of academic research that I could use in my literature review to back-up my choice of input device. 
If you'd like me to specify more feel free to let me know.

Comment: I think the question could be usefully rephrased around 'design guidelines for touch / non touch interfaces'

Comment: I've made the question more specific to my needs. Feel free to help

Comment: The voting machine being the hardware? I find that often the selection of the input method is mostly related to what hardware the application/ui you're designing is being deployed on.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an older article (2007) on [Mouse vs. Direct-Touch for tabletop displays](http://www.merl.com/publications/docs/TR2007-053.pdf). Back in university I saw a number of papers that compared the speed and accuracy of different input methods in completing certain tasks. I suspect that there have been more modern papers that have revisited these experiments.